Bounday Value Problem of an Inderminant Beam
I am trying to solve an indertminant beam using the finite difference method. I am using the fourth order equation to do this:
enter image description here
My beam is an 8m long beam with a pinned support at x = 0, and roller supports at x = 4 and x = 8. It is under a constant distrbuted load of 10 kN/m.
Firstly, I want to find the displacements of the beam, and I am comparing the results to a software package.
Strangely, when I discretize the beam to have 9 points I get the correct answer. To make it more accurate though I want to discretize much smaller, say 31 points. However, I get a completely different answer. when I do this.
Here is my code in MATLAB.
E = 2.1E+08
I = 18890/100^4
EI = E*I
L = 8;
x = linspace(0,L,9)
h = L/9
q = 10

% Attemp with 9 points

Matrix = [6 -4  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
        -4  6   -4  1   0   0   0   0   0
         1  -4  6   -4  1   0   0   0   0
         0  1   -4  6   -4  1   0   0   0
         0  0   1   -4  6   -4  1   0   0
         0  0   0   1   -4  6   -4  1   0
         0  0   0   0   1   -4  6   -4  1
         0  0   0   0   0   1   -4  6   1
         0  0   0   0   0   0   1   -4  6]

% Remove rows where displacement is zero
Matrix(:,[1,9,5]) = []
Matrix([1,9,5],:) = []

% Create the right-hand side

RHS = [q; 
       q; 
       q-1/h^4; 
       q + 4/h^4; 
       q-6/h^4; 
       q+4/h^4; 
       q-1/h^4; 
       q; 
       q]

RHS([1,9,5]) = []

% Find displacements in mm

y = ((inv(Matrix)*RHS)/EI)*1000

% Displacements with values from supports
y = [0;y(1:3);0;y(4:6);0]

% Attemp with 31 points
N = 31;
L = 8
x = linspace(0,L,N)
h = L/N
q = 10

% Construct matrix
mat1 = diag(ones(1,N)*6) ;                              
mat2 = diag(ones(1,N-1)*-4, 1);
mat3 = diag(ones(1,N-1)*-4, -1);
mat4 = diag(ones(1,N-2)*1, 2);
mat5 = diag(ones(1,N-2)*1, -2);

matrix = [mat1 + mat2 + mat3 + mat4 + mat5]

% Create right-hand side
rhs = (ones(1,N)*q)'
rhs((N+1)/2) = q - 6/h^4
rhs((N+1)/2 + 1) = q + 4/h^4
rhs((N+1)/2 - 1) = q + 4/h^4
rhs((N+1)/2 + 2) = q - 1/h^4
rhs((N+1)/2 - 2) = q - 1/h^4

% Remove rows where displacement is zero

matrix(:,[1,N,(N+1)/2]) = [];
matrix([1,N,(N+1)/2],:) = [];
rhs([1,N,(N+1)/2]) = []

% Find displacement in mm
y = ((inv(matrix)*rhs)/EI)*1000




If you run the code you will see that the calculation using 31 points gives a much, much larger values for displacements. I know the step size 'h' is much smaller, so that when you raise it the power of 4 you get a large value, but what I am doing wrong because the first discretization gives an accurate answer?
I thought that by increasing the number of nodes that I would get an even more accurate answer, but I didn't. The values are very, very different!
Here are the results that I'm trying to replicate:
enter image description here
When using 9 nodes I get a maximun deflection of 0.3201 mm. Using 31 nodes I get a maximum deflection of 40.99mm.
So clearly I have noticed that the right-hand side is very wrong. I have ammended it and no matter how many points I use I get the same values. However, I am still off my target when comparing the displacements to the software.
Here is my vector for the displacments calculated using the FDM:
     0
0.0210
0.0544
0.0928
0.1300
0.1614
0.1833
0.1934
0.1908
0.1758
0.1498
0.1158
0.0778
0.0412
0.0126
     0
0.0126
0.0412
0.0778
0.1158
0.1498
0.1758
0.1908
0.1934
0.1833
0.1614
0.1300
0.0928
0.0544
0.0210
     0

And this is how I have constructred the right-hand side:
Lambda = EI/h^4
rhs = (ones(1,N)*(q)/Lambda)'

I am just under half the target. Maximum displacement in the software is 0.347mm. Using FDM is 0.1934mm.

Fence issue, h = L/8

also h = L / (N-1)

Hi gboffi, changing that hasn't changed the answer.

Draw a 8 squares line on squared paper, then draw nine points on it, comprising the end points, What is the distance between the points? 1 square or 0.889 square? ፨ ፨ You changed  a wrong expression to the right one and the answer had not changed, what conclusion you may draw?

I don't know. I am a bit stuck. I mean, have I correctly calculated the right-hand side for the code that has the 31 nodes??

Is anyone there?

The results you are trying to replicate are, strange. Due to continuity the slope of the beam should be the same across the central roller, and due to symmetry the slope should be zero on both sides. ፨ ፨ ፨ That said, SO is about programming, and your problem doesn't  seem a programming problem.
